# Creating SOAP XML messages using WSDL or XSD or XJB file in Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, xsd, wsdl

There is a requirement by our client to create XML request messages from the WSDL file. The WSDL file has some 50 requests and responses. I am able to host to port 8080 the WSDL file and get response in SOAP UI for each request.

How to create those XML request and response messages(seen in SOAP UI)? Is there any SOAP UI jar files available to do the same work as SOAP UI?

The WSDL and XSD files are available and I am able to generate classes.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to compile the wsdl into java classes using the wsimport utility, which can be invoked via various maven plugins, like the [cxf-codegen-plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)  if you're using maven or gradle.  This will generate JAXB classes that represent requests and responses and JAXWS classes representing the actual services.  You would use the generated classes to create request objects, call the web service operations, and receive responses back, all completely in java.

Comment: I am able to generate classes of all the WS elements in the target folder, but how to create/build XML messages of each request and response like in SOAP UI software?

Comment: Your request would be represented by a java class, so you just construct that java class and call the setter methods on it to populate your request object.  You then pass that request object as an argument to one of the generated portType classes to call the web service.  Jaxb is used to convert your java classes to/from xml.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html

Comment: Can you please give me an example?